# Spacing gaps in Vertical border left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The current example uses a pseudo class to draw a line with small elements for main titles and sub titles. Every element which has a class `line` will require a line on the left hand side.

**Problem**: i am having to increase the height to `200%` to make it work. When the content is increased, that line extends further than it should.

As soon as the content increases, the timeline extends further: https://jsfiddle.net/ss189uva/

Is there a possibility of implementing this through `jquery`? as this needs to be flexible enough to withstand content areas and automatically adjust.

**Original example**:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.view-timeline-block {
  padding: 0 5em;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.view-timeline-block .ml-container {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.view-timeline-block .line {
  position: relative;
}
.view-timeline-block .line:after {
  background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 200%;
  left: -19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  width: 5px;
}
.view-timeline-block .active {
  position: relative;
}
.view-timeline-block .active:after {
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  width: 8px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.view-timeline-block .active-small {
  position: relative;
}
.view-timeline-block .active-small:after {
  background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 12px;
  left: -23px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-timeline-block">
  <div class="main-listing">
    <div class="title active">Testing name</div>
    <div class="content line">
      <p>testing name content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_name active-small">asdasdasdasd</div>
    <div class="sub_content line">
      <p>testing sub name content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-listing">
    <div class="title active">Timeline 2 name</div>
    <div class="content line">
      <p>timeline 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_name active-small">Timeline 2 sub name</div>
    <div class="sub_content ">
      <p>timeline 2 sub content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit `height` altogether and specify at least two (2) opposing positional properties for the dimension you want to set: https://jsfiddle.net/ss189uva/2/

```
.view-timeline-block .line:after {
    background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    left: -19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    width: 5px;
}
```

This is taking advantage of the fact that `absolute`ly positioned elements can be given dimension if enough properties are specified:

From [MDN's documentation for `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> Most of the time, absolutely positioned elements have `auto` values of `height` and `width` computed to fit the contents of the element. However, non-replaced absolutely positioned elements can be made to fill the available space by specifying (as other than `auto`) both `top` and `bottom` and leaving `height` unspecified (that is, `auto`). Likewise for `left`, `right`, and `width`.

By specifying `top: -15px;` and `bottom: -15px;` and leaving `height` as `auto`, you're ensuring that the top of the pseudo is `-15px` from the top and that the bottom of the pseudo is `-15px` from the bottom; the element's height give or take `15px`.